# Load Test for keras based GPU Machine Learning

Tags: python, keras

I am looking for a simple (self containing) keras based example that causes my GPU to run a decent long time with maximum usage.

With this I want to test the thermal behaviour of my machine.

Comment: To know if the example will stress your GPU like you want would be interesting that you gave us its specifications, like VRAM and amount of CUDA cores

Comment: It is a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, so there are 3584 CUDA cores and a VRAM of 11 GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about that but, you could try following this [Keras tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html), and instead of using 1K of images to each class use the whole dataset, 12,5K of images for each class. To make sure that you are using your whole avaible video memory, increase the batch size until you start to receive warnings when running the model. A good start point would be 64 as batch size. Try this and if you not receive any warnings, increase it a little. Let's say to 80. And run the model again. Based on my experience, I think that the "right" batch will be in the 64-128 interval.

**P.S.:** I don't remember exactly the warning message, but you surely will know that is it when seeing it